# FPS game UI theory

Tags: game-mechanics, gui, first-person-shooter, ui-design, interface

Are there any researches concerning FPS game interfaces? I'm interested in analyses of designing & positioning UI-elements. The only thing I can find are blogs and articles about immersion in video games. Do game-developers ever share any info? thnx

To be more specific, I want to know UX and ergonomic reasons for placing UI elements on the screen. I'm interested in things like:

- Where to place the radar (mini-map): in bottom-left, top-left, top-right corner? Is there any difference?
- What pros/cons for grid-like inventory against a scrollable list?
- How effective radial menus are?
- and more things which I can't imagine at this moment, but I'll definitely face them in future development...

I'm interested in both console and PC games.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you actually want to know and maybe we can answer your questions.

Comment: @netgoblin have you made a game yet? Before focusing on getting the UI right, you might want to first focus on making a fun game. You might want to even question the assertion that an advanced UI and HUD even add anything to your game. One of my favorite games thrives for the fact that it has none of those elements and focuses on making the player focus on the environment and what can be seen through human eyes and nothing else.

Comment: I work with a self-motivated team, and we make a shooter. None of us have experience in gamedev, but we do our best. Lots of gameplay stuff is already working, so I started to build a UI. I'm a web-developer with several years of experience. I have already designed a UI prototype based on data I was provided. I did some research, watched modern FPS. I thought that there might be some use cases how to build effective FPS UI. It's imposible to tell weather the game has an effective UI even if it is popular, imho.

Comment: I do like games without UI (diegetic, like "FarCry")... But you know, having NO interface is counterproductive, as far as, we try to add UI even in real life -> augmented reality =)

Comment: _"I still don't understand why moderators closed my question"_ You have _many_ questions in your post, and most of which have an answer that would begin with "It depends." This is the kind of topic that makes you question too broad. Additionally, if you posted as an answer what you added as an edit, the answer would be deleted because of being link only: if the author of the external link deletes the page (videos, in your case), the answer becomes useless for the site and for the users.

Comment: Someone could have answered like: "It depends..." and post a link, in case -> link, in another case -> link. But I got none. I do understand that my question is broad, as I wanted to get any info...

Comment: I've rolled back the attempts to "answer" this question through edits to the question itself. This isn't how StackExchange works. This question got closed because it doesn't fit within our guidelines; if you want help figuring out how it could be edited to scope it down to something that _is_ on-topic here, we can help with that. But trying to circumvent our rules isn't the way to do that. If you just want to get answers to your question or post information about what you've learned, a forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) may be a better place for that.